# Playframework always recompiles everything even just editing a css file

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I use play framework 2.5.x in my project and it always recompiles everything of the project even when I only edit a static CSS file and refresh the page.

The compilation is very slow now and it is extremely inefficient as it recompiles always even after making a minor change.

Build.sbt

```
name := "XXXX"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

resolvers += "Atlassian Releases" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/public/"

resolvers += Resolver.url("Morphia Repository", url("https://github.com/mongodb/morphia"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("AngularJS Repository", url("https://github.com/angular/angular.js"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("QRGen", url("http://kenglxn.github.com/QRGen/repository"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("Mibble", url("http://maven.cloudhopper.com/repos/third-party/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += "SNMP" at "https://oosnmp.net/dist/release/"

resolvers += "jitpack" at "https://jitpack.io"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, PlayJava)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.0.0",
  "org.mongodb.morphia" % "morphia" % "1.3.2",
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.4.2",
  "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "3.0-M8",
   "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.3",
  "net.sf.uadetector" % "uadetector-resources" % "2014.10",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0",
  "com.github.kenglxn.QRGen" % "javase" % "2.2.0",
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.10",
  "com.github.axet" % "kaptcha" % "0.0.9",
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.3.0",
  "org.json" % "json" % "20160212",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.7",
  "org.eclipse.paho" % "org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3" % "1.1.1",
  "org.jdom" % "jdom" % "2.0.2",
  "org.bitcoinj" % "bitcoinj-core" % "0.14.4",
  "com.madgag.spongycastle" % "core" % "1.56.0.0"

)
```

Plugin.sbt

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.15")

 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.1.0")

 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.4")

 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.8")

 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")

 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

 addSbtPlugin("org.irundaia.sbt" % "sbt-sassify" % "1.4.6")
```

Comment: More details? what build.sbt and plugins.sbt looks like?

Comment: @Al-Mothafar I added the details of these 2 files. Thanks!

Comment: This may be a known issue: [Application reloads on assets or public files changes](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7799)